# Button is not visible when I back press in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have three buttons inside the main activity.  When I click on any of the buttons, a new fragment opens.  Visibility of the three buttons disappears as soon as I click.  Clicking on the button opens the fragments.  When I press back from fragment, all three buttons in the man activity are not visible.  I want all three buttons to be visible when I come back to activity from fragments.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.bn1);
    btn1 = findViewById(R.id.bn2);
    btn2 = findViewById(R.id.bn3); 
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btn.setVisibility(GONE);
        btn1.setVisibility(GONE);
        btn2.setVisibility(GONE);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
       fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit(); }});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onClick. Once a button is clicked you set the visibility of the buttons to gone. Is this something you want to do? If so, in your create, set the visibility of the buttons to visible e.g btn.setVisibility(VISIBLE). Do this right under where you do your findViewByID's. Oncreate is called every time you initiate your activity, therefore you should do everything here you want your activity to have when starting up. Hope this helps

Comment: Can you share the code with me

Comment: Why do you make the buttons visible ? Help me understand what's your goal so I can help better